# Missing couple of elements in a vector

Tags: python, list, algorithm, set, combinations

I have a vector of numbers in `numpy`. For example :

```
a = [0,1,2,3]
```

and I have a list of vectors:

```
b = [[0,1] , [0,2], [0,3], [1,2], [1,3]]
```

what is the best solution in Python that allows me to find the missing couple of elements in b? In this case it would be:

```
c = [2,3]
```

I would add that it is not important the order of the elements, I only need the missing couple.

### A first try

I tried using the capabilities of the `sets`, that through `symmetric_difference` it gives the missing elements of a in an element of b:

```
for j in range(len(b)):
 list(set(b[j]).symmetric_difference(a)
```

But I do not manage to figure out the end of the algorithm or an alternative way.

Comment: Is there just one missing, or could there be several missing?

Comment: What should be the output if you also have `[1, 2]` missing? `[[1, 2], [2, 3]]` ? or `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: Could be several missing and the output should be a list of couples (e.g: [[1,2], [2,3]])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create all combinations with [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) then use `difference` in `set`  like below: *(this works for multi elements)*

```
>>> import itertools

>>> a = [0,1,2,3]
>>> b =  [[0,1] , [0,2], [0,3], [1,3]]
>>> c = itertools.combinations(a,2)

>>> res = set(c).difference(map(tuple, b))
>>> list(map(list, res))
[[2, 3], [1, 2]]

# for more explanation
>>> set(itertools.combinations(a,2))
{(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)}
```

Comment: Actually, `set.difference` takes any iterable, so `set(c).difference(map(tuple, b))` is enough.